# Hello. Wondering how I would go about loading all tabs in chrome to the same url which has been pasted simultaneously

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So essentially I need to change the url on many tabs at the same time and go to the new url on all of those tabs. I cant open new tabs, the pages have to switch from the url they are currently on to this new url simultaneously. So far I have this code. The code manages to go to switch to the new URL, however it doesnt do it across all open tabs, only on the tab which the console is open in which I entered the code into :

```
var destinationUrl = 'New_URL_Here.com';

// Get all open tabs
var tabs = Array.from(window.top.document.querySelectorAll('.tab'));

// Loop through the tabs and set the new URL
tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
    var iframe = tab.querySelector('iframe');
    iframe.src = destinationUrl;
});

// If the tabs don't have iframes, set the URL directly on the tabs
if (tabs.length === 0) {
    window.location.href = destinationUrl;
}
```

Really appreciate any help if anyone manages to solve the problem. Thanks so much for Your time.

Tried to change the URL of multiple Chrome Tabs at the same time to a new URL and load the pages simultaneously without any gap between load times. Was only able to load the new URL into one page, the tab which was directly correlated with the Java Console which was open on that page.

Comment: remember that Java and Javascript are [NOT THE SAME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245068/21252090)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You cant do that with JavaScript.

Why : when your writing code in java-script your working within a code execution environment specific to that 1 DOM.

Whilst you can easily open a new window using JavaScript, I'm sure that is as far as it goes. From a security point of view you wouldn't want JavaScript in one tab being able to query / access the DOM in another tab. Any site would then be able to gain access to your bank account details when you have it open as well, etc. if both sites were opened in separate tabs. 1 DOM one Scope,

1 DOM can Start another DOM.
No DOM Should be able to Manipulate the Browser, beyond its own Scope that would be a major Security risk and im pretty sure that would be a major bug that any broswer would want to patch . hope this help .